# TCL script breaks with "child killed: write on pipe with no readers"

Tags: bash, debian, tcl

After upgrading to Debian Jessie, the tcl motd I set up has been giving me a strange error on login *(hostname blanked out)*:

```
root     pts/0        XXXX-XX-XX-XXX-X Thu Jun 23 01:49:55 2016 - Thu Jun 23 01:                                                                     50:09 2016  (00:00)
child killed: write on pipe with no readers
    while executing
"exec -- last -F | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 "
    invoked from within
"set lastlog [exec -- last -F | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 ]"
    (file "/etc/motd.tcl" line 24)
```

I'm puzzled, because running the command myself I get the exact line that's printed on top, but it's not supposed to print anything when ran as part of the script, but rather set it as a value of a variable, as you can see from the referenced line in the error:

```
set lastlog [exec -- last -F | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 ]
```

What's happening here that's causing the mysterious error and how can I fix it?

Comment: I tried in my Ubuntu and this command works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by one of the subprocesses terminating with a non-zero exit code (which `exec` is very sensitive to), which in turn is caused by it still having output to produce despite the pipe being closed (a common issue with use of `head`). The simplest fix for you is to read the whole output of `last -F` into Tcl and to do the line chopping there. Fortunately, this is easy:

```
set lastOutputLines [split [exec -- last -F] "\n"]
set lastlog [lindex $lastOutputLines 1]; # Zero-based indexing
```

As long as the output of `last` isn't vast, this'll be quick enough.

Comment: For `git-gui` users: in my case I think the error was caused by a large commit (65k+ chars) that someone else did, my guess is that `git-gui` couldn't handle the message and throws the error. To fix, it was just commit via terminal, then the `git-gui` back to work as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub-shell invocation, where the shell does not mind the first command to terminate by signal, as in:

`set lastlog [exec -- bash -c "last -F | head -n 2 | tail -n 1"]`

This has the advantage of actually terminating the execution of "last" before it emitted its whole output, which is good if that output would be very long.